# Как обратиться к полю элемента инфоблока в разделе администрирования Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Задача такая: есть поля "Дата принятия коммерческой части" и "Дата продления комерческой части". Нужно сделать так чтобы при истечении срока 1-ой даты,поле со второй было неюзабельно. Как обратиться к 2-ому полю?? Как вообще добраться до верстки раздела администрирования??
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: никак, для этого вам надо будет править стили ядра грубо говоря, что не айс. Лучше сделайте отдельный интерфейс на фронте, а не в админке.

Comment: @user2736875 жаль очень(( сам не хотел в ядро влазить, но как то сделать надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, есть некое **свойство** у элементов инфоблока
Вам поможет вот эта статья, внутри живой пример
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=5258